# Is it safe to continue using [programmers.se] as a magic link?

Tags: support, new-site-name, hyperlinks, markdown

The point of [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000) is to link to a site quickly in comments.

`[softwareengineering.se]` is quite a mouthful. It looks like `[se.se]` is not a valid link to our site and it's questionable if it ever will be as a two letter abbreviation might cause naming conflicts in the future and/or might be reserved for bigger sites like `[so]` and `[su]`.

As a compromise, `[programmers.se]` still works for backwards compatibility (I guess) and is not quite as long as `[softwareengineering.se]`.

Will this backwards compatibility ever cease to exist?
**Is it safe to keep using `[programmers.se]`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think we'll ever break it, but you know what they say about saying "never"... :)

If that shortcut ever intentionally ceases to exist, we'll fix the comments to avoid breaking links. In the meantime, feel free to keep using it.

Comment: I was not even aware that `[programmers.se]` was a shortcut.